# Dataform.EditTemplate Use Display string

Tags: silverlight, dataform

Here is a part of my DataForm

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <df:DataForm x:Name="df1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CurrentItem="{StaticResource descriptor}" CommandButtonsVisibility="All" AutoGenerateFields="False" >
        <df:DataForm.EditTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                          <df:DataField Label="Capital Cost" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding CapitalCost, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
                    </df:DataField>
```

rather than explicitly specifying the Label "Capital Cost", I would like to use the Display data I have in the underlying type

```
  public class Descriptor     
    {
        [Display(Name = "Capital Cost:", Description = "The negotiated price of the car")]
        public double CapitalCost
        {
            get
            {
                return _CapitalCost;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > UsMsrp)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Capital Cost must be equal or less than US MSRP");
                _CapitalCost = value;
            }
        }
```

The description is carried over nicely to the interface, but I'm confused as far as the Name goes

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an IValueConverter that takes your property as input an returns the value of the DisplayAttribute.  [Here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/IValueConverter-The-Swiss-Army-Knife-of-Bindings-PropertyViewer-sample-is-a-WPF-Silverlight-visualization-and-debugging-aid.aspx) is an example that does something similar using the standard DisplayNameAttribute.